# How to list of last installed package names?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to get list of last installed packages from `/var/log/apt/history.log` file. I want to keep that list on a file for using it later to remove last installed packages with `apt remove` command.

My problem is, I can't figure it out how to get that list from this line:

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "Install:" | tail --lines=1
Install: alsa-base:armhf (1.0.27+1), libgirepository-1.0-1:armhf (1.58.3-2, automatic), python-gi:armhf (3.30.4-1, automatic), python-dbus:armhf (1.2.8-3), python-gobject:armhf (3.30.4-1), gir1.2-glib-2.0:armhf (1.58.3-2, automatic)
```

**to this format:**

```
alsa-base libgirepository-1.0-1 python-gi python-dbus python-gobject gir1.2-glib-2.0
```

I tried some `sed` regex but without success (*I'm not very good at `regex` and `sed`*). So, what should I put the last part of the script to achieve my goal?

```sh
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "Install:" | tail --lines=1 | ????????????
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a single call to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '/Install:/{sub("Install: *","");$1=$1;print}' FS=":[^)]*)(, )?" ./history.log
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat ./history.log
foo:  blah:armhf (1.0.27+1), bar:armhf (1.58.3-2, automatic), baz:armhf (3.30.4-1, automatic)
Install: alsa-base:armhf (1.0.27+1), libgirepository-1.0-1:armhf (1.58.3-2, automatic), python-gi:armhf (3.30.4-1, automatic), python-dbus:armhf (1.2.8-3), python-gobject:armhf (3.30.4-1), gir1.2-glib-2.0:armhf (1.58.3-2, automatic)

$ awk '/Install:/{sub("Install: *","");$1=$1;print}' FS=":[^)]*)(, )?" ./history.log
alsa-base libgirepository-1.0-1 python-gi python-dbus python-gobject gir1.2-glib-2.0
```

Comment: I am geting `awk: run time error: regular expression compile failed (missing '(')` error.

Comment: `FS=":[^)]*\)(, )?"` I need to escape second `)` parenthesis to solve that error.